# Selenium Webdriver C# - Stop browser opening on program start up

Tags: performance, selenium, browser, startup

I am writing a program for automation testing and it works fine. I do however have an issue with the amount of time it takes from the program to start up. This is down to the face that I initialize the IWebdriver = new firefoxDriver() in the public partial class so to allow for all functions to access the driver class with ease and no fuss.

So when i load the program the browser loads which takes maybe 15/20 seconds followed by the GUI I have built. Does anybody know a way of making the "driver" global but not initializing the browser until I call it in a function? i.e. I can load my program and fiddle with the variables etc and then when I am ready I click a button, then the browser loads and executes the function all without have the Iwebdriver = new firefox() in each function separately. Also the reason I have coded it this way (making it global) was due to different browser session issues. It would not see other browsers outside of the initial one on start up

Here is the basic code I am working with

public partial class Main : Form
    {

```
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Initialize it the same way but make it static:*

```
Public static IWebDriver Driver;
```

*And then set it to FirefoxDriver where you need it to open the browser:*

```
Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: Worked a charm! Thank you! I can see that i may run into issues with selecting the correct window, but I can deal with that if/when it arises.

Comment: Glad to help! If this was the correct answer I would ask you to mark it as one. Speaking of issues with switching pages please take a look ad driver.Switch() you can find it also here on SO.

Comment: will do, thanks! it seems to use the default window generated by the code, however I can see issue down the line coming from this. I will take a look at the driver.switch. hopefully this will work as all other references to switching between browser windows seem to be either outdated or in Java. Thanks Again!

Comment: No problem hope you are going to find a good solution for your problem. Good luck!